# pie chart use line point to percentage text

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I can use chartjs(it's open source and easy), realize like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzYH7.jpg
But I want to like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcHUe.jpg (this is one demo of http://www.highcharts.com/demo)
it's use some line point to the description.(I want to realize it, but it's need to pay, and I want to commercial use it), is there some any open source code can do it or modify the chartjs to realize it.

Comment: thanks, But I dislike let the description in the each slice.